How to load google map javascript API in phantom js?
I am trying to load google map JavaScript API in phantom js but failed to load.
`var page = require('webpage').create();

//Handle console messages
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log('Console: ' + msg);
};

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3';
// Handle errors
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
    console.error('Error: ' + msg);
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
        console.error('  -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line);
    });
};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.log('Resource error: ' + resourceError.url + ' - ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

//Handle resource received events
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    console.log('Resource received:');
    console.log('  URL: ' + response.url);
    console.log('  Status: ' + response.status);
    console.log('  Time: ' + response.time + ' ms');
    console.log('  Content type: ' + response.contentType);
};
page.open('URL/map1.html', function(status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        console.log('Page loaded successfully.'+status);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(google);
             if (typeof google !== 'undefined' && typeof google.maps !== 'undefined') {
                 console.log('Page loaded successfully.');
             }
            page.render('map11.jpg');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 20000); // Wait for 10 seconds
    } else {
        console.log('Failed to load the page');
    }
});
`


I tried this code URL/map1.html has code to create google map but failed satisfying my requirement.
I need a solution for the same

Would it be possible for you to provide a sample app using an online code sandbox?
